# Assigning Leads to queue in Apex

Tags: apex

I want to assign Leads to a Queue in APEX.
I know the queue's name e.g. 'New Leads Queue'
When I query the DB for the QueueSobject I see it has no field with the queue's name.
How can I find the Queue ID in order to assign the lead to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code you're seeing with `QueueSObject` doesn't seem to be valid, I found this though:

> You will find queue name in object Group:
>
> Select g.Type, g.Name, g.Id, g.Email, g.DoesSendEmailToMembers,
>   g.DoesIncludeBosses  From Group g.

So maybe checkout the `Group` object?

Answer (score 2):

It is available via the QueueId lookup field, the relationship name is Queue, so

```
Select Queue.Id from QueueSObject where Queue.Name = 'Test'
```

Assign the Lead Owner to `Queue.Id` as returned in the Query above.